# Firebase Unity HTTP cloud function with authentication

Tags: authentication, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-functions

Cloud Functions has [HTTP endpoints](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#add_the_addmessage_function). And we can make sure that [only authenticated users use them](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/authorized-https-endpoint). For that, we need to [obtain the current user's token](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/authorized-https-endpoint/public/main.js#L62) in the client.

At the same time, when testing your game in the Unity Editor, you can't use Firebase Authentication. You can still test your game by [using a service account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/start#optional_editor_setup_for_restricted_access). There is no authenticated user object, which prevents us from getting a user token. Without a user token, we cannot use authenticated HTTP endpoints.

So, when we are testing the game in the Unity Editor, can we get a user token so that we can use authenticated Firebase HTTP endpoints?